# Play Wav file from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Im building an app that teaches  kids how to say the letters of the alphabet in a jigsaw puzzle form making up letters made of images. Each time the click one into place it creates click sound and when they complete it plays a well done sond followed by the sound of the letter also when they click on the letter it will also play the sound of the letter. Simple in theory but complex for a newb like myself

I have say 40 sounds i want to load into an array and then be able to call each one separately  at any given time when a user clicks on a letter or object.

I have successfully managed to load a single sound using a basic example I found online however with my needs being a lot bigger than a single sound I feel an array would better suit unless you can advise on a better way?

The code bellow detects if a user has dropped the puzzle in the correct place and then plays a sound to show its in place. Im showing you this to just explain what i have done so far im aware this would need to be redone with the array.

Please can anyone tell me how to create an array of sounds and then select a certain sound to play at a given point.

Many thanks

```
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch
                         locationInView:self.view];

if ([touch view] == image1)
{

    CGRect rect1= CGRectMake(562, 260, 103, 302);
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect1,touchLocation))
    {
        CGRect myFrame = image1.frame;
        myFrame.origin.x = 562;
        myFrame.origin.y = 260;
        image1.frame = myFrame;
        imagea =true;
        [image1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];


        NSURL* audioFileURL1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"mouse1" withExtension:@"wav"];
        sound1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL1 error:nil];
        [sound1 play];



        if(imagea && imageb && imagec) {



            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WELL DONE!!"
                                                            message:@"You have learnt the letter A"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue"
                                                  otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];



            NSLog(@"All images set and locked in place");}


       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't load the sounds in advance. Create an NSArray of sound filenames and fill it in your view controller's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   soundNames = @[@"sound1", @"sound2", @"sound3", @"sound4", @"sound5"];
}
```

Then create a method playSoundAtIndex: that takes a numeric index, uses it to load a sound, and plays it:

```
- (void) playSoundAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;
{
  if (index> soundNames.count-1)
    return;
  NSURL* audioFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: soundNames[index]
    withExtension:@"wav"];
  AVAudioPlayer *soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: audioFileURL
    error:nil];
  [soundPlayer play];
}
```

That's about it.

If you find you need to play these sounds in more than one view controller, you might want to create a sound manager singleton that you can call from anywhere in your app. Do a Google search on the singleton design pattern in Objective C. There are examples here on SO, even.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off thinking object oriented. It sounds like you want a class which contains an image, and a sound to play when the image is touched. You could subclass UIImageView for this, add a UITapGestureRecognizer, and play the sound when the tap is detected. If you have 40 images and 40 corresponding sounds you could define those in a plist (as an array of dictionaries). Load the plist, iterate over the array, and for each dictionary use that to set your subclass' image and sound.

Comment: That sounds logical however I will have 40 sounds give or take and only 26 of those will be related to a letter or image. The others will be sounds effects ect for the app. Potentially i could create a plist for the letters and letters. However wouldnt it be better to keep them separate?

Comment: You could have two plists, one for the letters, one for the other sounds. Just depends how you want to use them really. Hard to say without knowing exactly how your app should work.

Comment: Sorry I should of given more detail. Basicly its an app that teaches kids how to say the letters of the alphabet in a jigsaw puzzle form making up letters made of images. Each time the click one into place it creates click sound and when they complete it plays a well done sond followed by the sound of the letter also when they click on the letter it will also play the sound of the letter. Simple in theory but complex for a newb like myself